# Windows 10 UI Glitch and other problems - I dont even know how to approach and fix all of these

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bsod

Lately, I'm having some problems with my laptop. There are times when the UI gets messed up (as you can see in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWohd.png) and image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhVY9.png)). Also, I'm getting random 100% disk usage spikes and 100% CPU usage spikes. But there are also times when everything runs smoothly for days.

Also, there are times when the laptop fails to boot (it stays stuck in BIOS, not detecting the SSD). There are other times when it does detect the SSD, but it returns "A disk error occurred - Press Ctrl-Alt-Del to restart". Sometimes, after 10-15 restarts, it boots successfully.

Sometimes I'm having blue screen (bsod) errors with stop codes like: 'memory' or 'unexpected store exception'.

I also noticed one time when the laptop refused to boot (the CPU fan was not even starting to spin) when the laptop was not plugged in. After I plugged it in, the boot sequence started. But that happened only once (and I find it odd).

On my experience, it seemed that some hardware malfunctioned. I tested the RAM - no errors. I tested the SSD - no errors. I tested the file system - no errors. I've tested and upgraded the BIOS. Nothing seems to offer a permanent fix.

The only temporary fix I found was opening up the laptop and replugging the SSD in the SATA connector. But that lasts for a few days and I can't really open up my laptop every other week... :))

Funny enough, if I'm installing Ubuntu, everything runs perfectly.

Is there anything I can try to detect the problem?
Thank you!

Please note that there are times when everything runs perfectly...

ASUS X556UB
Intel Core i7-6500U @ 2.5GHz
4096MB RAM
Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB
Windows 10 Education 64-bit

Comment: This could be a number of things, as @BWhite mentioned in his answer, one of them being malware. Have you run an in-depth antivirus scan lately? The fact that everything's peachy in Linux, and all breaks loose when in Windows, makes me think that either your graphics card driver has gone AWOL, or that your PC is infected somehow. High CPU usage would indicate that as well, along with the cryptic error messages. Have you tried to restart your video driver with Win + Ctrl + Shift + B when that happens?

Answer (score 0):

You've clearly got a couple of different issues.
Not powering up and not detecting the SSD are clearly hardware issues.
The BSOD is always a software issue, although it could be caused by an underlying hardware issue like memory or SSD issues.
So I would start with dealing with those. The BSOD will be a bad driver, the trick is to figure out which one. MS provides tools for that. Google "debug bsod windows 10" for steps.
On the SSD, it's either the computer or the SSD, so divide and conquer. Go to the local computer store and ask for a cheap refurbished drive, known to work, that you can test with. Might be less frustrating to have them test it out for you.
On the memory tests, they can tell you if memory is bad, but if it says good, it just means it didn't find anything. I had a case where I ran six different memory checkers and they all said good. The seventh finally said bad. Sadly it took me so long to find it that the chip was a month out of warranty.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Apparently the SSD was not directly connected to the motherboard, it was connected using another small hidden intermediary board.

That small board had a loose connection with the motherboard, causing all the problems. ‍♂️

Thanks for all the help! :)